# Get index of Row Number and Column Name which is having Null/Blank Values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe in which I need to go through the for loop and see which is the row number and what are the column names(not column values) in that row that is having blank/null values. Then store that row number and column names in that row which are having blank/null values in two separate variables (Row_Number and Column_Names). The reason for going through the loop is I want to log the empty rows on row by row basis which is to be sent to HTTP Post request in JSON form. The end application only received the JSON format.

| ID | Name | Dept | Zipcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 |  | Finance | 173212 |
| 233 | Alex |  |  |
| 344 | Ruther | Sales | 173453 |

Output in for loop for 1st Iteration:

```
Row_Number = 1  
Column Names = [Name]
```

Output in for loop for 2st Iteration:

```
Row_Number = 2  
Column Names = [Dept, Zipcode]
```

Output in for loop for 3rd Iteration:
Nothing as all field are not null/blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this snippet to get the list of indices with null values:

#### per column

```
nulls = df.isnull()
(nulls.mul(df.index.values, axis=0)
      .where(nulls)
      .apply(lambda x: x.dropna().astype(int).unique())
)
```

output:

```
ID          []
Name       [0]
Dept       [1]
Zipcode    [1]
```

#### per row:

```
nulls = df.isnull()
(nulls.mul(df.columns, axis=1)
      .where(nulls)
      .apply(lambda x: x.dropna().unique(), axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
0             [Name ]
1    [Dept , Zipcode]
2                  []
```

#### edit: using iterrows:

```
for idx, r in df.iterrows():
    nulls = list(r[r.isnull()].index)
    if nulls:
        print(f'row {idx}: those columns are null:', nulls)
```

output:

```
row 0: those columns are null: ['Name ']
row 1: those columns are null: ['Dept ', 'Zipcode']
```

Comment: Actually I want in a row by row basis and not in a single go !! The solution I am looking is for column names (and not values) per row basis..

Comment: @AnishGupta same logic, just apply on the other axis ;) see updated answer. regarding the one by one, you can compute and then loop later for export

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need to perform the loop before only as there are other fields in the log that needs to be filled on row basis. For eg. {"RunDate" : "current_date", "DateTime" : "current Time", "Customer_ID" : "cust_id", "File_Name" : "file_name", "Error_Code":" error_code", "Error_Message" : "error_message","Row_No" : "", "Column_No" : "[list of columns]"}